not able to view File Contents in Remix IDE
REMIX IDE.
When I click on a File in File Explorer contents are not visible on the right hand side.
attached screencapture.( infact file is not highlighted also.)
thanks
Uday

Please try after clearing the browser cache and reloading Remix IDE.

SYED ASAD KASMI When I clear browser cache and cookies node_modules folder gets deleted.  I am able to open and edit the files but clearing Cache and Cookies deletes node modules folder. I guess node_modules occupies lot of space and hence not able to open smartcontract .sol files. I require node_modules for my programs.
